# How to retrieve both form values and names in form of an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form with a selection tag. This form can post many options at a time. When ever I assign a variable to the selection name e.g `$name=$_POST['name'];` It only `echoes`  arrays of the form values and not the options. I want a situation where by a variable can be assigned to the `value[] array`  and the `name[]` array separately so that they can be used in a `php script` to manipulate a database. I need your assistance. Thanks.

Comment: you'll get only values , for your requrmnt , generate a array with key&value with that select box values, and check with POST value and do manipulate the db

Comment: Where is your code? Your question title and your actual question don't seem to match. Do you want two arrays whereby one array as the selected answers from your form and other array contains the name value associated with each selection chosen?

Comment: what i understand you want `$form_keys = array_keys($_POST);$form_value = array_values($_POST);` now `$form_keys` is a numeric array of all your form field name, and `$form_values` is a numeric array of all values of those form fields.

Comment: `@walex` did you get what i said above?

Comment: If you want to know now only the values of what was selected, but also the name, you will need to leverage jQuery to get the names and possibly Ajax as well to take the value from your jQuery and create your second PHP array.

Comment: @ the_pete can you help me with the jQuery or Ajax code. I just started learning php and haven't learnt JS nor AJAX yet. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<select name="options">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
$value = $_POST['options'];
```

$value will hold the value that you have selected

Comment: This only addresses part of the question. Along with an array of values, it appears that he also wants an array of the option "names".

Comment: I want both arrays of values and the selected options.